# Segmentation error range-based for loop over neighbouring elements c++

Tags: c++, loops

I am trying to loop over a vector and need to manipulate the current element as well as the next one. I am currently trying this, but get an seg fault:

```
  for (const auto& element : * vec)
  {    
    const ClassObj * obj1 = &element;
    const ClassObj * obj2 = &element + 1;
    if(!obj2) break;
  }
```

Why does this not work and do you have a better solution?

Comment: Don't use range-based loop for this, it won't work. You need a regular iterator loop or plain index-based one.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Technically, it may work even with range-based loop, just one would need to, e.g., compare `obj1` with `&vec.back()`. Which would be a pretty ugly solution.

Comment: When handling the last element of the vector, `&element + 1` will go out of the range of the vector.

Comment: Ensure that you don't walk off the end with your `+1` offset.

Comment: @Gupta This is legal if you don't dereference such a pointer.

Comment: @DanielLangr But he has mentioned that he need to manipulate the current + next elements.

Comment: @Gupta I believe that `if(!obj2) break;` should check for the last iteration. It won't work, of course, but can be checked otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to use a range-based for loop here, but it's kind-of ugly:

```
for (const auto& element : vec)
{    
   const auto* obj1 = &element;
   if (obj1 == &vec.back()) break;
   const auto* obj2 = &element + 1;
   ... // do whatever with *obj1 and *obj2
}
```

Most people will likely prefer a standard index-based for loop:

```
for (size_t i = 1; i < vec.size(); i++)
{    
   ... // do whatever with vec[i - 1] and vec[i]
}
```

Note that I deliberately did not write

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size() - 1; i++)  // don't do this
```

since this would result in *negative overflow* for an empty vector (and very bad things might happen then).